# React Native: How to change/navigate the Screen as a Childcomponent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, screen, navigator

Every little help is appreciated very much!

I got an Avatar as a Navigator, which should allow me to navigate through some screens! Some other Screens should be reached only by the my home screen. But when I press on the Button in the Avatar, nothing happens. I don't understand how and why, but I believe I made a mistake in the stackNavigator somewhere? Just to avoid any misunderstanding, the code below is shortened to avoid filling the page with unnecessary information, so it doesn't reflect 1:1 what you see in the screenshots.

[Home Screen which should change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZaRF.jpg)

[Avatar Screen through which I should be able to change the Home Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JTWE.jpg)

The goal is to be able to change which Screen is displayed in the `<AppContainer/>` through the `<Avatar/>` component below.

I tried with a onPress function inside the Avatar.js to call `this.props.navigation.navigate("Agenda")` but the screen didn't change. At least I got rid of the errors thanks to passing the navigation prop. I believe I made kind of a scrub mistake since i'm not experienced with react native, I hope some of the more experienced users can help me with that :) furthermore I don't think the  screen itself is important to solve this, it's just a class component with panresponder and animated view.

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";

import Avatar from "../coreComponents/Avatar";

import ScHome from "../screens/ScHome";
import ScNewMedi from "../screens/ScNewMedi";
import ScCalendar from "./ScAgenda";

const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: ScHome,
    },
    Medis: {
      screen: ScNewMedi,
    },
    Agenda: {
      screen: ScCalendar,
    },
  },
  {
    headerMode: "screen",
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    backBehavior: "order",
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppStack);

export default class ScDefault extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StatusBar
          barStyle="light-content"
          backgroundColor="transparent"
          translucent
        />
        <AppContainer />
        <Avatar navigation={this.props.navigation} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Comment: Why is the avatar placed outside of the AppContainer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to access navigation outside the Appcontainer where the navigation is not available.

Easy fix :
Moving the Avatar component inside one of your main screens(ScHome,ScNewMedi,ScCalendar) then you will have access to navigation and everything will work as expected.

Workaround :
Let say the requirement is to have the Avatar outside the AppContainer then you have to use something like a navigation service.

The code would be as below

```
let _navigator;

const setTopLevelNavigator=(navigatorRef) =>{
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

const  navigate=(routeName, params) =>{
  _navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      params,
    })
  );
}

//Change your app.js
 return <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <AppContainer
    ref={navigatorRef => {
      setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
    }}
  />
 <Avatar navigate={navigate} /></View>;

   //Inside the Avatar onPress you can can do this
   onPress={()=>this.props.navigate("Home")}
```

You can refer the docs for [more details](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/navigating-without-navigation-prop/)